# dplyr `pivot_longer()` object not found in subsequent code

Tags: r, dplyr, tibble

Using the example dataframe:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(Location = (c("Location A", "Location B")),
             Shop = c("Store A", "Store B"),
             Employees = c(5, 10),
             Sales = c(1000, 3000))
df %>% pivot_longer(c(Employees, Sales), names_to = "parameters", values_to = "values")
df
```

I managed to gather employees and sales into one column using the pivot longer function

```
df %>% pivot_longer(c(Date, Shop), names_to = "parameters", values_to = "values")
```

I manage to get the tibble produced, however, in a subsequent code where I try to produce a graph, I run into an error that the object parameters cannot be found. Does anyone know why this issue keeps occurring?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidypaleo)

ggplot(df, aes(x = values, y = location)) + 
  geom_colh(width = 0.5, position = "dodgev")+ facet_abundanceh(parameters, scales = "free_x")
```

Comment: Make sure you are assigning your new "long" object a name, either the same one or a new one: e.g., `df1 <- df %>% pivot_longer(c(Date, Shop), names_to = "parameters", values_to = "values")`.  Then you can use the `df1` object in later code.

Comment: I did that as well, but I keep running into the same issue

Comment: Can you update your question so folks can see everything you did (including assignment)?  That way people can follow your exact code and then see if they can reproduce the problem.